# Kernel Panic upon wake from sleep

Tags: sleep-wake, mojave, kernel-panic

my TB MBP (Mojave) has been panicking quite often lately upon waking from sleep, and here's the latest panic report:

```
Anonymous UUID:       27FCCF62-843B-76C2-32A6-3E4F215D3E53

Sun Feb 10 13:24:22 2019

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8004c01e33): "a freed zone element has been modified in zone kalloc.192: expected 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef but found 0, bits changed 0xdeadbeefdeadbeef, at offset 16 of 192 in element 0xffffff80617a1f40, cookies 0x3f0011fccdc16a2e 0x535211c27a2e0e5"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4903.241.1/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:1168
Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f7d2b7d0 : 0xffffff8004baeb0d 
0xffffff81f7d2b820 : 0xffffff8004ce8653 
0xffffff81f7d2b860 : 0xffffff8004cda07a 
0xffffff81f7d2b8d0 : 0xffffff8004b5bca0 
0xffffff81f7d2b8f0 : 0xffffff8004bae527 
0xffffff81f7d2ba10 : 0xffffff8004bae373 
0xffffff81f7d2ba80 : 0xffffff8004c01e33 
0xffffff81f7d2bbd0 : 0xffffff8004bbb0c4 
0xffffff81f7d2bc40 : 0xffffff8004c4e766 
0xffffff81f7d2bd70 : 0xffffff8004b8ff35 
0xffffff81f7d2bdb0 : 0xffffff8004b905d2 
0xffffff81f7d2be50 : 0xffffff8004ba3573 
0xffffff81f7d2bef0 : 0xffffff8004cc17bb 
0xffffff81f7d2bfa0 : 0xffffff8004b5c486 

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: configd

Mac OS version:
18D42

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 18.2.0: Thu Dec 20 20:46:53 PST 2018; root:xnu-4903.241.1~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1970B070-E53F-3178-83F3-1B95FA340695
Kernel slide:     0x0000000004800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8004a00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8004900000
System model name: MacBookPro14,3 (Mac-551B86E5744E2388)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 309150451706377
last loaded kext at 96001045659410: com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8bc79000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
net.pulsesecure.PulseSecureFirewall 9.0.2f5
com.symantec.ips.kext   14.2.1f52
com.symantec.nfm.kext   14.2.1f52
com.symantec.internetSecurity.kext  14.2.1f52
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   5208
com.symantec.SymXIPS    8.2.2
com.apple.filesystems.afpfs 11.1
com.apple.nke.asp-tcp   8.0.2
com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.10
com.apple.fileutil  18.306.12
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.23.46
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.7.0d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.5
com.apple.kext.AMDFramebuffer   2.0.4
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000   2.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.28.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDALSService 1
com.apple.AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics  3.28.4
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   282.10
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   282.10
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    6.0.10f1
com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry    1
com.apple.driver.AGDCBacklightControl   3.28.4
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.12.11
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphics  12.0.4
com.apple.driver.eficheck   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGFXHDA    100.1.40
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.5.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPCHPMC   2.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.28.4
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.kext.AMD9500Controller    2.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEmbeddedOSSupportHost 1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelKBLGraphicsFramebuffer   12.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleVirtIO    2.1.3
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.kext  407.200.4
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 40
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0
com.apple.AppleSystemPolicy 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 138.2
com.apple.driver.AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
com.apple.filesystems.apfs  945.241.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelI210Ethernet 2.3.0
com.apple.private.KextAudit 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   190
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.serial 6.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   900.4.2
com.apple.security.SecureRemotePassword 1.0
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4100HWLibs 1.0
com.apple.kext.AMDRadeonX4000HWServices 2.0.4
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 282.10
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    527
com.apple.iokit.IOAVBFamily 710.1
com.apple.plugin.IOgPTPPlugin   700.7
com.apple.driver.AppleSSE   1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.AppleGPUWrangler  3.28.4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUARTTransport  6.0.10f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerTransport  6.0.10f1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.18d1
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   530
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 282.10
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 282.10
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.14d1
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 6.0.0d8
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.28.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTv1   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUARTCommon   3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleOnboardSerial 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSkywalkFamily 1
com.apple.kext.AMDSupport   2.0.4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.28.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    404.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    530.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   255.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.2.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBiBridge    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  315.6
com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   206.5
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.cdc    5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.networking 5.0.0
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub    1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIUpAdapter   2.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   5.5.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext    1
com.apple.driver.AppleActuatorDriver    2410.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   208
com.apple.driver.AppleHSBluetoothDriver 138.2
com.apple.driver.IOBluetoothHIDDriver   6.0.10f1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   6.0.10f1
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  2410.5
com.apple.driver.AppleInputDeviceSupport    2410.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    55
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  55
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    3.0.60
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   1200.12.2
com.apple.driver.corecapture    1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    5.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    5.5.8
com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme    3
com.apple.iokit.IONVMeFamily    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    4.7.6
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.1.0
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.driver.AppleHPM   3.3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 6.8.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2CController    3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 3.0.60
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  3.0.60
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI    1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI   1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostPacketFilter   1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 900.4.2
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 493.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleEffaceableStorage 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTDM    456.230.1
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.kext.CoreTrust    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageDriver  145.200.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   408.200.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   408.200.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.KernelRelayHost    1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily 1.2
com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBCommon 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBusPowerController    1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSEPManager    1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOSlaveProcessor   1
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  47
com.apple.iokit.IOTimeSyncFamily    700.7
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.4
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0

EOF
Model: MacBookPro14,3, BootROM 185.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.8 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.45f0
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 630, Intel HD Graphics 630, Built-In
Graphics: Radeon Pro 555, Radeon Pro 555, PCIe
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, LPDDR3, 2133 MHz, 0x802C, 0x4D5435324C31473332443450472D30393320
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x173), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.1 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.2)
Bluetooth: Version 6.0.10f1, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Thunderbolt Ethernet Slot 1, Ethernet, en9
PCI Card: ethernet, Ethernet Controller, Thunderbolt@69,0,0
PCI Card: pci1b73,1100, USB eXtensible Host Controller, Thunderbolt@70,0,0
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: iBridge
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: USB5734
USB Device: USB5734
USB Device: USB audio CODEC
USB Device: USB2734
USB Device: Keyboard Hub
USB Device: Apple Keyboard
USB Device: Hub Controller
USB Device: USB2734
USB Device: Hub Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 39.2
Thunderbolt Device: Thunderbolt 3 Express Dock HD, Belkin International, Inc., 1, 19.1
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 39.2
```

Does anyone have any idea why this could be happening? I've tried consulting Google, but nothing seems to stand out.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the first thing to try when diagnosing kernel panics is to remove 3rd party kexts & their associated apps/structures...

```
net.pulsesecure.PulseSecureFirewall 9.0.2f5
com.symantec.ips.kext   14.2.1f52
com.symantec.nfm.kext   14.2.1f52
com.symantec.internetSecurity.kext  14.2.1f52
at.obdev.nke.LittleSnitch   5208
com.symantec.SymXIPS    8.2.2
```

I don't specifically know all those except for Little Snitch, which is normally a well-behaved app; but you do seem to have 3 different sets of firewalling & security running alongside each other, which is generally not recommended - they tend to fight.